# UI issue with nil title in UIAlertView iOS 8 beta 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, alert, uialertview, ios8

I have an issue related to UIAlertView while running our app on iOS 8. 
I am showing an alert with title as nil. It was working fine in iOS 7 but now UI looks odd.

I have attached screenshot here.

[image]
One solution I found is that when I provide empty string @“” it looks okay. See below screenshot. But I am not sure if the issue I mentioned is bug in beta iOS 8 version or if there is any other better solution. Even with the solution it's not exact as it was in iOS 7.

[image]

iOS 7 - showing alert view with title as nil. Screenshot here.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has been the best practice for me to use `initWithTitle:@""` for `UIAlertView`, `UIActionSheet` since iOS 6 because I was facing a design issue during that time when I was using `initWithTitle:nil`. I tried to find back, I couldn't find it what exactly is the reason.

From your screen shot on iOS 8, I think there is a change of **view hierarchy on UIAlertView** for iOS 8. I think `Auto layout` might be implemented on the view hierarachy as well as you can see the messageLabel jump up to the titleLabel.

I can not be sure because the view hierarchy for UIAlertView is private.

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html

But, I use the code:-

```
NSLog(@"%@",[self.alertView description]);
```

**Result on iOS 7.1:**

```
<UIAlertView: 0x7fb3c05535b0; frame = (18 263; 284 62); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fb3c0519810>>
```

**Result on iOS 8.0:**

```
<UIAlertView: 0x7bf64840; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x7bf648f0>>
```

I am not sure why the UIAlertView frame for iOS 8 is **(0 0; 0 0);**

Like Mike said, I think you should learn to use `UIAlertController` for iOS 8.

Answer (score 11):

The closest I could get with iOS 8 was by setting the title instead of the message:

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location field required." message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

[image: UIAlertView iOS8 title set]

It should be noted, however, that `UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS 8 and, if you're going to be using separate code paths for iOS 7 and iOS 8, you should be using `UIAlertController` instead:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Location field required."  message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}]];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I got the same results with both methods.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to get decent message alignment without the bold font by:

1. Setting the title to @"" instead of nil, and
2. (If IOS8) prepend a "\n" in front of the message.

> ```
> UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" 
>                                     message:@"\nLocation field required." 
>                                     delegate:nil 
>                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
>                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
> ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.
it is working on my side
xcode version 9.2

```
UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                              alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                              message:nil
                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
UIAlertAction* btn1 = [UIAlertAction
                       actionWithTitle:@"OKAY"
                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                       handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                       {

                       }];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```