# UIAlertView and UIActionSheet not displaying properly in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8

`UIAlertView` and `UIActionSheet` not displaying properly in iOS 8, its hiding the view controller, also In alert view title is not displaying. I am running the app from Xcode 5.1.1.

[image: Action Sheet]

[image: Alert View]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you added any category for ViewController in your application. like below shown

```
@implementation UIViewController (CustomeAction)
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title{
// YOU CODE///
}
@end
```

This may the issue. I have solved by removing this category `- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title.`

Note: From iOS 8, UIAlertViewController is inherited from  UIViewController. If you use category method, it will be effect on UIAlertView & UIActionSheet titles.

You can refer apple docs at [UIAlertController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html)

Comment: welcome, if you required to set title then you can write category for UINavigationItem.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted, that UIAlertView and UIActionSheet is deprecated in iOS 8. You can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559901/ui-issue-with-nil-title-in-uialertview-ios-8-beta-5) or the [apple link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html). May be it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code using UIAlerController for XCode 6 and IOS 8

```
UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                 alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                                 message:@"Your Message"
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

   UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                        actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                        handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                        {
                            [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                        }];
   UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                            actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                           handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                           {
                               [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                           }];

   [alert addAction:ok];
   [alert addAction:cancel];

   [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

For ActionSheet

```
UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                     alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                                     message:@"Your Message"
                                     preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
```